# Is there a good reason more developers don't namespace custom jQuery events?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dom, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

jQuery events have a namespace concept built in for easy and safe unbinding of just the events you've added.

These namespaces, however, don't prevent collisions when different plugins trigger the same basic event. For example, if plugin A triggers the `hide.foo` event and plugin B triggers the `hide.bar` event, any handler listening for the `hide` event is going to be invoked twice, even with the namespaces.

This can cause problems when plugins trigger overly generic names like `open`, `close`, `show`, `hide`, `start`, `end`, etc., yet so many plugins out there (even ones from large libraries like jQueryUI and bootstrap) trigger these generic events without a second level namespace.

So here's my question. It seems like a second level of namespacing would be prudent, both to distinguish your events from other plugins and from standard DOM events. The convention could be something like `namespace:eventName` or `namespace:eventName.secondaryNamespace` if using the standard jQuery dot notation.

But nobody seems to be doing this, so I wonder if there's some compelling reason not to. Does anybody know?

**Update:**

To provide a more concrete example, suppose I'm using plugin A which triggers the `show` and  `hide` events on tooltips as the user hovers over certain text. Since events propagate and my DOM is constantly changing, I decide to bind my event listener to the `document` element to catch the `show` and `hide` events from all tooltips.

Then, a few weeks later, I add plugin B to my app which also triggers the `hide` event after the user dismisses an alert message. Now all of the sudden my tooltip code is going to be invoked more than I want it to because both the tooltip and the alert message plugins are triggering events with the same name.

Comment: "Why don't more people use X" is very hard to answer. "Is there a good reason not to use X" is a good question. +1

Comment: Can you give a few good examples of where this would be useful? that may help answer your question and/or give it some context.

Comment: @JanDvorak I've updated the questions title.

Comment: @KevinB I've added an example.

Comment: I can say that with the way jquery does namespaced events, giving the event a namespace won't change the behavior you are seeing. Triggering hide.foo vs just hide will still trigger events bound to just hide. You would have to literally use different event names, which is exactly what jQuery UI is doing in most cases ( are there any cases where they dont? )

Comment: Note however that the documentation for jQuery UI is not complete and is in the process of being updated. Events are usually prefixed with for example dialogopen rather than just open.

Comment: @KevinB I just looked at the jQuery 1.9.1 source and they trigger the `create`, `open`, and `close` events all over the place for many of their widgets. `dialogopen` is not in the source at all.

Comment: I'd have to go through each widget 1 by 1 to be sure, but i'm basing this off of this issue: https://github.com/jquery/api.jqueryui.com/issues/47 several jQuery UI widgets have start and stop events, but they're all prefixed with for example drag, slide, drop, etc. *They don't seem to all follow this setup though.*

Comment: I guess with that in mind, it's up the the plugin developer to decide if he/she wants to make the events unique or not. It makes sense to make them unique, though that kind of change at this point would cause more problems than it will solve with jQuery UI.

Comment: Also, just to add, it appears as though most if not all jQuery UI widgets prefix their events in this way. `dialogcreate` for example. It is built into the widget factory's `_trigger` method.

Comment: @KevinB ahh, I see that now. Good call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that both libraries I specifically mentioned (jQueryUI and Bootstrap) either do or are planning on prefixing their custom events.

Here's what jQueryUI does in its custom `_trigger` method:

```
event.type = ( type === this.widgetEventPrefix ? type : this.widgetEventPrefix + type ).toLowerCase();
```

This allows you to define your own prefix via `this.widgetEventPrefix` on any included widget or widget you make with the widget factory.

Bootstrap hasn't implemented a prefix yet but plans on doing it in the next major version (3.0.0).

Here is what @fat said in this [Github issue](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/4104):

> In the future we'll probably namespace everything with bootstrap
>   (data-attrs and events - but that will be a 3.0.0 thing, because it's
>   breaks backwards compatibility)

And here is [his tweet](https://twitter.com/philwalton/status/268078072778067968) in response to my question about it.

--

As for me, I've decided to name my custom events with one of the following patterns (depending on context) to avoid any possible conflicts with other libraries in the future.

```
prefix:event.namespace
appname:widgetname:event.namespace
libraryname:widgetname:event.namespace
```

Comment: Let me get it right. The solution is to use `:` as a separator for names to avoid collisions? If so, yes, that is my suggestion. The premise of the question is to use jQuery event namespaces for avoiding conflicts, which is a bad idea. If you did that, callers wanting to register an event with their own namespace (so they can easily remove it later) would not be able to do so because jQuery doesn't support multiple periods in event names, from what I've seen in their source code.